# ASP.NET Dynamic Data performance issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic-data, asp.net-dynamic-data

I am experiencing performance issues with an ASP.NET Dynamic Data Entities Web Application.

The application consists of 4 main entities. The tables contains between 100 and 8000 rows. I'm using the ListDetails view. Opening a single record takes 4 to 6 seconds on average, wich is not acceptable.

The first thing I investigated was the performance of the database, but this was ok. Then I tried excluding the filters without a result. Finally I exluded most columns by setting the ScaffoldColumn attribute to false in the metadata classes. This gave a major result, loading forms in miliseconds. Then I started testing with more and more columns included. Everytime the number of columns increases, the performance gets worse.

The number of fields for the main entities go up to 50. But isn't is strange that a form containing only 50 fields takes seconds to load?

I hope someone has a good idea to boost the performance, or at least has a decent explanation for this behaviour. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: `The first thing I investigated was the performance of the database, but this was ok` - does this mean that you have tested query execution during Dynamic Data page load with Profiler and duration was OK? Does this mean that you have checked SQL Server indexes in your database and it was OK? Also check how many values load in your drop-down list filters.

Comment: The profiler showed that the query execution was OK.I did not run something like the index tuning wizard. I also excluded all filters but that didn't result in a better performance.

Comment: Have you tried to open default `List.aspx` page instead `ListDetails.aspx` page and then click on details action? Are you using `AllowPaging` property of `GridView` control on `ListDetails.aspx` page? Please, try to load only default `List.aspx` page and tell us the results.

Comment: AllowPaging is set to True and I'm using the GridViewPager. Using the default pages I discovered that List.aspx and Details.aspx performs OK, but when I click edit and load the Edit.aspx page the performance drops dramaticly. Strange thing is that there are no dropdowns loaded with large amounts of items. So what can cause the lack of performance? Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: Are you using default `Edit.aspx` or custom one?

Comment: Please, check duration of the query that is executed when you load `Edit.aspx` page, there is a probability, in my opinion, that the problem is connected with SQL Server Indexes. Try to perform rebuild, reorganize indexes and then update statistics.

Comment: Thank you for the pointers Konstantin. The Default_Edit.ascx EntityTemplate is customized by the initial developer of the application to rearrange the fields and implement tabs. This piece of code uses multiple loops (some nested) wich cause the delay. Thanks for your help!